# Xamarin: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ado.net

In Xamarin. I've been trying to make communications between my Web API and my Xamarin project. Here's the code for my controller:

```
//  GET api/values
    public List<string> Get()
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        values.Add("Value 1");
        values.Add("Value 2");
        return values;
    }
```

And here is my GET request in my **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public async void BindToListView()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://10.0.2.2:#####/api/Values");
        var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Posts>>(response);
        lv.ItemsSource = posts;
    }
```

Whenever I try to run both my Android application and my Web API Application. I keep getting this exception:

```
    Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.'
```

I've tried pasting this into my **MainActivity.cs**, but it still doesn't work.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, cert, chain, errors) => true;
```

I've been having this problem for months now, and its driving me crazy. Am I missing something? I'm fairly new in developing Xamarin applications, and this is a problem that I can't seem to resolve.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time in reading this.

Comment: Are you using a self signed certificate? If so, see: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/android-certificates/
Also ignoring certificate errors is a poor practice as it defeats the purpose of having certificates in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

```
//Use this, it worked for me. 

HttpClient client;

public class datastore {
   var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            
   httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = 
   (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

   client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
}

//... use the client to make request. it will bypass 
//the ssl certificates verification.
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is an easy solution for local testing with self signed certs.

Comment: Thanks, I was writing an app for a local network where I don't have access to the server; that uses self signed. Perfect for debugging my app!!!

Answer (score 1):

For Android you should do something more .

#### in Forms ,create an interface

```
public interface IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService
{
  HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler();
}
```

#### in Android implemented the interface:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(HTTPClientHandlerCreationService_Android))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
  public class HTTPClientHandlerCreationService_Android : CollateralUploader.Services.IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService
  {
    public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
    {
      return new IgnoreSSLClientHandler();
    }
  }

  internal class IgnoreSSLClientHandler : AndroidClientHandler
  {
    protected override SSLSocketFactory ConfigureCustomSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
      return SSLCertificateSocketFactory.GetInsecure(1000, null);
    }

    protected override IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
      return new IgnoreSSLHostnameVerifier();
    }
  }

  internal class IgnoreSSLHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
  {
    public bool Verify(string hostname, ISSLSession session)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And when you call the method `Get`

```
public async void BindToListView()
{
  HttpClient client;

  switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
  {
    case Device.Android:
      this.httpClient = new HttpClient(DependencyService.Get<Services.IHTTPClientHandlerCreationService>().GetInsecureHandler());
      break;
    default:
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
      this.httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
      break;
  }

  var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://10.0.2.2:#####/api/Values");
  var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Posts>>(response);
  lv.ItemsSource = posts;
}
```

In addition, I suggest that you can use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` because it has implemented the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged** . Otherwise the UI will never been updated .

Comment: is there an implementation for iOS as well?

Answer (score 0):

> Attempting to invoke a local secure web service from a .NET MAUI app
> running in an Android emulator will result in a
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException being thrown, with a
> message indicating that the trust anchor for the certification path
> hasn't been found. Similarly, attempting to invoke a local secure web
> service from a .NET MAUI app running in an iOS simulator will result
> in an NSURLErrorDomain error with a message indicating that the
> certificate for the server is invalid. These errors occur because the
> local HTTPS development certificate is self-signed, and self-signed
> certificates aren't trusted by Android or iOS. Therefore, it's
> necessary to ignore SSL errors when an app consumes a local secure web
> service.

> This can be accomplished by passing configured versions of the native
> HttpMessageHandler classes to the HttpClient constructor, which
> instruct the HttpClient class to trust localhost communication over
> HTTPS. The HttpMessageHandler class is an abstract class, whose
> implementation on Android is provided by the AndroidMessageHandler
> class, and whose implementation on iOS is provided by the
> NSUrlSessionHandler class.

> The following example shows a class that configures the
> AndroidMessageHandler class on Android and the NSUrlSessionHandler
> class on iOS to trust localhost communication over HTTPS: C#

```
public class HttpsClientHandlerService
{
    public HttpMessageHandler GetPlatformMessageHandler()
    {
#if ANDROID
        var handler = new CustomAndroidMessageHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            if (cert != null && cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                return true;
            return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
        };
        return handler;
#elif IOS
        var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler
        {
            TrustOverrideForUrl = IsHttpsLocalhost
        };
        return handler;
#else
     throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Only Android and iOS supported.");
#endif
    }

#if ANDROID
    internal sealed class CustomAndroidMessageHandler : Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler
    {
        protected override Javax.Net.Ssl.IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection connection)
            => new CustomHostnameVerifier();

        private sealed class CustomHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, Javax.Net.Ssl.IHostnameVerifier
        {
            public bool Verify(string hostname, Javax.Net.Ssl.ISSLSession session)
            {
                return Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier.Verify(hostname, session) ||
                    hostname == "10.0.2.2" && session.PeerPrincipal?.Name == "CN=localhost";
            }
        }
    }
#elif IOS
    public bool IsHttpsLocalhost(NSUrlSessionHandler sender, string url, Security.SecTrust trust)
    {
        if (url.StartsWith("https://localhost"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
#endif
}
```

> On Android, the GetPlatformMessageHandler method returns a
> CustomAndroidMessageHandler object that derives from
> AndroidMessageHandler. The GetPlatformMessageHandler method sets the
> ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback property on a
> CustomAndroidMessageHandler object to a callback that ignores the
> result of the certificate security check for the local HTTPS
> development certificate.
>
> On iOS, the GetPlatformMessageHandler method returns a
> NSUrlSessionHandler object that sets its TrustOverrideForUrl property
> to a delegate named IsHttpsLocalHost that matches the signature of the
> NSUrlSessionHandler.NSUrlSessionHandlerTrustOverrideForUrlCallback
> delegate. The IsHttpsLocalHost delegate returns true when the URL
> starts with https://localhost.
>
> The resulting HttpClientHandler object can then be passed as an
> argument to the HttpClient constructor for debug builds: C#

```
#if DEBUG
            HttpsClientHandlerService handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
#else
            client = new HttpClient();
#endif
```

A .NET MAUI app running in the Android emulator or iOS simulator can then consume an ASP.NET Core web service that's running locally over HTTPS.

**for more details on how to Connect to local web services from Android emulators and iOS simulators check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Xamarin Application, I only needed to test the Web API and didn't care about the HTTPS protocol.

What I did was follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check). And removed HTTPS from my app to enforce only HTTP request. Helped me to fetch my data from the API.

Comment: You should make your response useful without the link, as it may be changed or taken down in the future.