# Java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, maui

I am making an app in .net maui. I hava also made a local webapi where i can get all registrated users. I have run the application on the andriod emulator from a Windows machine. But i always get the error: Java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found!.

I followed the documentation on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services?view=net-maui-7.0#trust-your-development-certificate

But still i get this error message. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the web server running locally or externally? I don't claim to know about this but seems to me that link is a way to allow comms to a localhost but if you need to access a remote host then you might need the certificate embedded in the app. I think recent android builds don't trust the general store if the certificate isn't bundled.

Comment: Have you googled that error message?  This has been discussed many times

Comment: You can check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376095/xamarin-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certifi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122287/java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-pa), it talks about this error you refer to, that could be helpful to you.